# estimating class homework

Tags: estimation

I have an estimating contracts class. the assignment calls for bidding on a excavating job. I am not able to determine the of amount of time I will need a supervisor for, but the assignment calls for paying one. It gives the per hour amount and how many hours per day. I having trouble with where I get the info to determine the amount of days it will take for the whoe

Comment: Hi rell, the background you share is hardly understandable. What's more the question you ask seems to be unanswerable--how one could possible answer how much time would take something that isn't defined in a question. Please update the question so it is more specific, otherwise you don't really give anyone a chance to answer it in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Supervisor/Superintendent for every day that the excavation operation is going on. Excavation crews cannot work without supervision. It's a safety issue. So figure one Supervisor day for every crew day.